# Keyframes not saving rotation

Tags: keyframes

I select the rotation, but when I go to save it as a keyframe, it will either revert immediately, or wit until I move to the next frame and back and it will still have reverted.[Video to problem](https://youtu.be/Er5NNfCgbc8)

[image]

Comment: Something in your video looks strange. The viewport and timeline say you are on frame 27, and also the number in blue frame which usually shows where the playhead is shows a 27. However the playhead itself, the vertical blue line, is on frame 8. Also the timeline shows that only X rotation has a keyframe on frame 27, however the colors on the _Location_ and _Rotation_ values are all the same, indicating they all have keyframes there. Maybe you could upload the file to investigate this further? I guess a file with only the keyframed camera would be enough. It seems like you are not on frame 27?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann - The thing with Timeline is remapped time. Go to *Render Properties > Frame Range > Time Stretching >*  where the *Old* value is set to 30 (or *New* value is set). So I guess keyframe is saved, but at frame 27 (that is highlighted).

Comment: @vklidu I didn't see the remapped time in the video... better explain that in an answer to Isaac, I don't need to understand it because I never use this ;)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann ... OK ... sorry for that, I direct my comment to you since your comment sounds to me it is strange for you so I thought you would be interested what is behind. Issac's issue is rotation, that is caused by another issue. BTW You are right, there is not time remap visible, the presence of it is indicated by timeline and frame number offset.

Comment: @vklidu The reason why it is only saving the rotation for X instead of XYZ as you mentioned in your deleted answer is that he's not keyframing in the viewport with I > _Insert Keyframe_ > _Rotation_ but in the _Timeline_ with Right-click > _Insert Keyframe_ which only keyframes the selected channel - in this case X... this is clearly visible in the video.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann ... so you are ready to create answer :)

Comment: @vklidu The problem is not the single X rotation keyframe - it's the reverting of the rotation setting as the question explains. And I guess that's because the keyframe is not placed on the frame where the playhead is... so you are probably indeed correct with your time stretching - which I never use as I said so I will probably not be able to answer that. The question is not "why is there only a keyframe on X?"

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I completed the answer here to finish this conversation :) The combined answer is - it saves rotation as suppose to at real frame 27, frame 8 with playhead line is just a visualisation of modified time (that is my part). Rotation is not saved because axis name has to be selected for keyframing from contextual menu in timeline (your part of correct answer). :)

Answer (score 1):

OK ... so the thing here is

- to add keyframe by selecting *Insert Keyframes* operator from contextual menu (right-click) in Timeline (or Dope Sheet) **you have to select a channel name** in the left row. (Thanks to @GordonBrinkmann comment)

[image]

- or press *I* > *All Channels* (instead of right-click)
- or press *I* in *3D Viewport*.

---

Just a footnote ... The timeline's line at frame 8 and timeline's number in header at frame 27 indicates you are using *Render Properties > Frame Range >* **Time Stretching** ... like *Old* value set to 30 (or *New* value like 330).

[image]

In this case - the keyframe is saved, but under frame 27 (see highlighted keyframe in timeline) and specifically in your case - the keyframe is saved only for selected X axis (for the reason described above).

You rotated Y axis that is not selected - so was not saved.